# Deploy Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Can anybody tell me how to deploy website that uses silverlight navigation application and silverlight enabled wcf services?

Thanks
Mohak

Comment: The answer to questions like this is usually msdeploy. :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdeploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is in one project, WCF and web (Silevrlight compiled to the client bin) just run the web deploy in visual studio. If they are seperate, deploy the wcf service, insure you have a client access policiy in the wcf root and the deploy the silverlight web application.

Brad

Comment: Hi Brad!                                                         Thankx for your answer.I am getting some problem in Server.when i use silverlight enabled wcf service,the server cannot produce result.it is failing to process .svc MIME Types.Can you give some idea how can i configure the server??

Comment: You may have register the wcf service model in IIS, you can do this with ServiceModelReg.exe in the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vXXXX folder. Just run it from the command line with the /i